# Emptying the database through Django's `manage.py`

Tags: database, django

I would like to completely empty the entire database, restoring it to the way it was when I just created it, using Django's `manage.py`. Possible?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

What you can do to flush the DB and not have any migrate(south) problem afterwards is:

first, reset the data from the DB:

```
python manage.py flush
```

second, fake the migrations that are already applied:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

third, if you have some fixture to load:

```
python manage.py loaddata my_sweet_json_file
```

Comment: Haven't you skipped the steps after flush to (1) remove migrations history from `<app>\migrations` & (2) run schemamigration with --initial option?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use [flush](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-flush).

That will reset and restore everything in your entire database, regardless of which app or project the models are in. If you have a few databases, you can specify a single one in particular by using the `--database` switch

Examples:

```
python manage.py flush
python manage.py flush --database mydatabase
```

Comment: The `syncdb` action that `flush` does after flushing is causing problems with my migrations and fixtures. Can I cancel it? I want it to just delete everything.

Comment: Well you could always just go drop the database and syncdb again.

Comment: Yeah well, the point was not to interface with the db directly.

Comment: @RamRachum I just posted bellow how to mitigate that migration/fixtures problems!